# IOS MDM App Push Success/Failure?

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm

We built an MDM server using a Mac Mini.  We successfully set everything up and pushed out 2 enterprise apps to about 50 iPads.  All of the iPads where updated to the latest version of ios as of last Tuesday, all of the devices are at least an iPad 2.. All are connected to WIFI

The question is these 2 apps successfully pushed to 90% of the ipads but the remaining few ipads will not download the app?  The device will receive the push but after a few minutes will say that the app can not be downloaded at this time?  I haven't been able to get my hands on a unit that is doing this yet so I'm hoping that someone may have come across this problem before.  Is there a setting on the pad that would stop an app from downloading?... I've ruled out the network because some of the ipads that are not working are connected to the same network that others have downloaded the app on.

I'll post console information here as soon as i get some but again hoping someone may have an idea that I can have them try remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use an MDM service called AirWatch and we are having the same issue.  I gave them a call thinking it was our server but from what he says (as of right now) Apple is having APN issues

Comment: Ahh Interesting... I tried to log into the apple developer site as well and it's down as well...

Comment: I just called Apple to confirm... They said it is most likely the problem.  Apparently their WWDC tickets wet on sale this morning... they have been taking services offline trying to allocate resources for the ticket traffic.  They are expecting services to come back online in the next few hours and at the latest 24 hours...